# Proof that for infinite sum: $\sum_{m\geq n}^\infty \frac{(\lambda (1-p)t)^m}{(m-n)!}=((1-p)\lambda t)^n e^{(1-p)\lambda t}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I prove that:

$$\sum_{m\geq n}^\infty \frac{(\lambda (1-p)t)^m}{(m-n)!}=((1-p)\lambda t)^n e^{(1-p)\lambda t}$$

Comment: The left side not even defined.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Better now?

Comment: Perhaps the denominator is $(m - n)!$.

Comment: Is $n$ a free choice, or should you be considering $\sum_n \sum_{m \geq n} \ldots$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am interpreting $m-n!$ as $(m-n)!$. Just change the variable from $m$ to $j=m-n$. Let $x=\lambda (1-p)t$. You will get $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^{j+n}} {j!}$. Pull out $x^{n}$ and use the series for $e^{x}$.